# Using JButton to start simple animation

Tags: java, swing, animation, event-dispatch-thread, thread-sleep

I am following **HeadFirst Java 2nd Edition** and trying to perform a simple animation of  a circle moving diagonally from one point to another on the click of a button.
I am using JPanel to draw the circle and ActionListener interface to get event from the button.
When I directly call the animate function from 'main()' , the animation works fine. But when i try to do so after the click of button, the program freezes and directly displays the end result.

Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    public class SimpleAnimation{
    int x=70;
    int y=70;
    JFrame frame;
    MyDrawPanel drawPanel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleAnimation gui=new SimpleAnimation();
        gui.initialize();
        // gui.animate();               //animation method
    }

    public void initialize(){
        frame=new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        drawPanel=new MyDrawPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,drawPanel);
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        JButton button=new JButton("Click me!");
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST,button);
        button.addActionListener(new OnclickListener());
    }

    public void animate(){
        for (int i=0;i<130 ;i++ ) {
            x++;
            y++;
            drawPanel.repaint();
            try{
                Thread.sleep(50);
                }catch(Exception e){}
            }
        }

        class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel{
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                g.setColor(Color.white);
                g.fillRect(0,0,this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
                g.setColor(Color.green);
                g.fillOval(x,y,40,40);
            }
        }

        class OnclickListener implements ActionListener{
            public  void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                animate();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You should look at [`Timer` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html). You shouldn't sleep on the UI thread (or do any other non UI logic) as it will block redrawing your GUI.

Comment: See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to repaint() puts a repaint request into a queue; you may be thinking that it immediately repaints the screen.  Your requests are all stacking up in this queue waiting to be executed, and then effectively all getting executed at once.

You need a timer, not a call to Thread.sleep(), to put distance between your different animations.  There is a timer provided in java.util, but you instead should use the one in Swing.

I recommend a google search on "animation in Java", where there are several sites that explain things in detail.

Comment: Thanks , I'll have a look at it

Comment: Thanks pal!!, I had to use timer to fix it!!

Comment: "and then effectively all getting executed at once", Not too sure about that! Only one repaint is executed, no matter how many times you call .repaint() in actionPerformed().

Answer (score 0):

I find that you have the `animate()` function declared in class `SimpleAnimation` but you are calling the function in the class `OnclickListener`. This is not possible. When in the class `OnclickListener` in method `actionPerformed` you are calling the function `animate()` this means `this.animate()`. So the program tries to locate the `animate()` function in the `OnclickListener` class which cannot be found which should give a compile error.

In order to do what you want, you have the pass the reference of the `SimpleAnimation` to the class `OnclickListener` in a variable say `simpleAnimation` and then call `simpleAnimation.animate()` and it should work.

Comment: The code runs just fine. Im using Inner classes, thats why the code runs.